# What is wrong with a beginner following the Rock workout schedule?

Tags: workout-routines, muscle, strength-training, gym

So I am about 5 months into training and I am struggling to come up with a suitable routine. My gym buddy suggested me to do what [rock does](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/train-like-dwayne-the-rock-johnson.html), which is simply-put, one muscle group a day, 2 day rest, repeat (arms/legs/back/chest/shoulders).

But from what I have read, I will reach super-compensation way before I repeat the muscle group in my schedule, as I do it 1/7 days. So to reach super-compensation, I need to hit every muscle group about twice a week, but that seems to be a lot to cover in a day(about 6 different workouts for each group). So I am not convinced that what I am doing now is the best schedule for me.

So what should be my approach to get efficient results. Should I take super-compensation into account? Workout multiple muscle groups and hit  them more often? Or should I just hit one muscle group a day like the rock does?

P.S I do take protein supplements and follow a fair diet.

Height - 6',
Weight - 173 lbs,
BF% - ~15%,
Squat - 120 lbs,
Bench press - 135 lbs,
Dead-lift - 105 lbs.

Comment: Have you been consistent in the 5 months, and, what does your current routine consist of?  Additionally, what are your fitness goals?

Comment: Consistent - fairly yes (+80% attendance). current routine - split routine, 5 days a week, chest/shoulder/tricep, legs, back/biceps/shoulders, legs, chest/triceps. cardio all days. The problem here is too many workouts, I would end up spending 2+hours. goals - muscle build/mass.

Comment: What are you strength gains since you started 5 months ago? Please give your Height, Weight, Build (bf%) and your numbers for your big 3 (Deadlift, Squat, Bench). More information the better when it comes to designing routines.

Comment: Allegations of drug use aren't really what the comment section is for. Ideally, it is for refining/clarifying questions or answers. If you can substantiate your suspicions (Other than the experimentation he admitted to when young), you can offer that as part of an answer.

Comment: @JohnP it's a worthless discussion since for a person NOT on gear, this trianing/eating regiment makes no sense at all. So yes, it's relevant to mention.

Comment: @cbil- Again, if you have information supporting your stance, present it as an answer. Somply parroting "won't work without 'roids" is mindless drivel. Maybe you could write an amswer explaining *why* it would not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common mistake made by beginners to weight training is to assume that an increase in training volume (eg. more training days) is required for muscle gains.  Based on your comments and goals (eg. muscle build/mass ), I would offer that your main problem is not the type of routine to follow, rather, it is over training.

If you plan to train drug free, you'll need to learn to walk a fine line between training **volume** and **recovery**.  That would imply selecting a training routine that best fits **your** needs.  And, while there's **no** perfect training system that fits **all** people, learning what works for you and constantly adapting it to avoid training plateaus is more important than training to a specific system.

Muscular gains don't come from a **specific** training program.  They are the result of consistent, hard work over a lengthy period of time, coupled with proper nutrition and rest. Spend time learning about yourself and finding what works for you.

Answer (score 3):

What you have linked seems to be, at its heart, a fairly simple 6 day body split. This is not a new or special routine; in fact, a lot of routines commonly work on a 3 day repetition cycle for the exact reasons your identify.

Super-compensation is simply your body over compensating during a recovery period. By hitting those muscles in super compensation you will be able to train harder and get more effective results. The below image explains it well.

[image]

This routine is comparable to a 6 day, +1 rest day, push-pull-legs (PPL) routine but instead of pushing/pulling, the focus is on hitting every single muscle group twice over the week in the super-compensation period.

### Your Question:

Is the Rock's routine suitable for a beginner? It is not optimal, a beginner should really focus on a compound lifting routine to build strength (like starting strength, 5x5 stronglifts) before moving onto a PPL or body split. That way you will be able to get significant noob gains and then hit progressive overload on your PPL/split without stalling too much.

Is it suitable for you? I will edit my answer once you provide the information I asked for the comments.

Comment: Things that people often forget when looking at training schedules of people like this, Dwayne Johnson is that a) he's been training his entire life and has progressed to the point where he knows that this is the best way for him to train at the moment, and b) his father, and his father's father, were both wrestlers, i.e. rather athletic individuals. So his genetic athletic potential is probably quite good.

Comment: @DarkHippo completely agree, not only is his genetic makeup support bulking and muscle gain but this routine is being performed on one of the best bases around. He is doing this routine after years of working out building his base of fitness.